# How to sort an array of full location addresses in relation to their proximity to the current user's location?

Tags: javascript, sorting, geolocation

I have an array of businesses. Each business has a location field in the form of a full address: 
**Example of business:**

```
 { 
   name: "MSBIZ",
   location: "347 Broadway, New York, NY, USA"
 }
```

I am also getting the current user location. An example :

```
   {
    "city": "New York",
    "continent_code": "NA",
    "continent_name": "North America",
    "country_code": "US",
    "country_name": "United States",
    "ip": "74.68.108.199",
    "latitude": 40.7651,
    "location": Object {
    "calling_code": "1",
    "capital": "Washington D.C.",
    "country_flag": "http://assets.ipstack.com/flags/us.svg",
    "country_flag_emoji": "",
    "country_flag_emoji_unicode": "U+1F1FA U+1F1F8",
    "geoname_id": 5128581,
    "is_eu": false,
    "languages": Array [
        Object {
          "code": "en",
          "name": "English",
          "native": "English",
        },
      ],
    },
    "longitude": -73.9638,
    "region_code": "NY",
    "region_name": "New York",
    "type": "ipv4",
    "zip": "10065",
  }
```

I want to sort my array of businesses in relation to proximity to the current user' s location. How do I do this in the most effective way ?

Comment: Straight line radial distance is simple to calculate based on lat/long differences. If that is sufficient precision (vs  driving distance) can loop through array and do calcs for each location (formula easy to find) and store in the object then do a numeric sort using that property for sort comparison

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.geodatasource.com/developers/javascript) is good example of how to calculate distance, you can then sort it with that param.